# $?<variable> in sh

Tags: shell, sh

Recently I come across below code ...

```
if [ ! $?target -o $target = "" ]; then
    echo "Target is not set"
fi
```

I am curious to understand logic of above code snippet.
It seems that it is checking, if I am correct, whether `"$taget"` is set or not or `"$target"` is empty or not.

I google to find how `$?variable` works, but I didn't find any relative search results.
So please help me to understand how it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't valid for sh on my linux system.  I get:


     [: 5: =: unexpected operator

Comment: Ian, that's because you're using the wrong shell :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some shells, `csh` for example, `$?xyz` will evaluate to 1 if `xyz` is set, otherwise it evaluates to 0.

All that snippet is doing is checking if either `$target` is not set at all or if it's set to an empty string. In both cases, it assumes it's not set.

Note that this is different from `bash` for example where `$?` is the return code from the last executed command. In that shell, you'll simply get the return code followed by the variable name, such as `0target`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your script is slightly mis-quoted,

```
if [ ! "$?target" -o "$target" = "" ]; then
    echo "Target is not set"
fi
```

This will indeed print "Target is not set" when $target is unset, However A much more reliable method for doing this would be:-

```
if [ "x$foo" = "x" ]; then
    echo "foo is not set"
fi
```

Comment: In csh `$foo` complains when foo is undefined instead of returning an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

I put "#!sh" at the top, line 1 and ran it on a Mac OS 10.5.Terminal window, which says its bash...

The original script, with [ ! "$?target" -o "$target" = "" ]'
gets
    try.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments

The version IanNorton suggests works:
    Target is not set

I get the same results with #!bash on line 1, and no shell specification on line 1.

Your mileage may vary...

Comment: A downvote but no comment? I tried with "#!csh" on the first line as well and neither the original nor IanNorton's version work.